# Tree view control in teleric

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, treeview, telerik-mvc

I am working on asp.net mvc 3. I am using the Teleric Controls for the Tree view structure in my application. I want to buil/ construct the Tree view in Controller . and populate it to its view. 
Some how which is the best method to prepare the Tree view in Controller and pass to View OR I can use Teleric Tree view object model ,build the tree and pass it to View vai ViewData. But how to convert ViewData to Telerik Treeview Control ?

Comment: infact i am starting to code. but before that i am anlyzint the scenario. suppose in my controller, Action building the tree. and storing it in ViewData["MyTree"] and need to render this tree control on view then how to convert this to Teleric TreeView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Html.Telerik().TreeView()
>   .Name("TreeView")
>   .BindTo((IEnumerable)ViewData["Customers"], mappings =>
>   {
>                   mappings.For(binding => binding
>                           .ItemDataBound((item, customer) =>
>                           {
>                               item.Text = customer.ContactName;
>                               item.Expanded = ((string[])ViewData["ExpandedNodes"])
>                                                  .Contains(item.Text);
>                           })
>                           .Children(customer => customer.Orders));
>
> > })
> >     .ClientEvents(events => events
> >     .OnCollapse("updateTreeViewState")
> >     .OnExpand("updateTreeViewState")

Taken from
http://www.telerik.com/support/kb/aspnet-mvc/treeview/persisting-treeview-state-in-cookie.aspx

Comment: This is right...but i able to build the control using object model in my controller and save it to ViewData. where as in view i can just biind it to Html.Telerik().TreeView() directly...working for me